# Loading A Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am trying to load a partial view using the following in my index.cshtml. But the btn load is not doing anything I have jquery loaded fine using the stadnard mvc internet template.

```
    <input id="btnLoad" type="button" value="LoadRegsitrationForm"/>
    <br/>

    <!-- partial view container -->
    <div id="divPartialViewContainer" >
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btnLoad').click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/HtmlControlTest/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/html',
                    //data: JSON.stringify(model),
                    success: function (content) {
                        $('#divPartialViewContainer').html(content);
                    },
                    error: function (e) { }
                });
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Then in my HomeControler cs I have the following

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HtmlControlTest()
    {
        return PartialView("HtmlControllerTest");
    }
```

Then in my HtmlControllerTest. I just have a few labels and textboxes. I did not no how to show this code here as it was converting it to elements.

The reason I am using partial views is that I am wanting to try and build a form builder and was thinking this is best way to go but if I have to do a post every time I want to load a partial it wont be very efficient anyway of doing what I am doing below more efficient.

Comment: Can you see any errors in your console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Correct your ajax call as :

```
      $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/HtmlControlTest/',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/html',
                datatype:'html',     <------------
                success: function (content) {
                    $('#divPartialViewContainer').html(content);
                },
                error: function (e) { }
            });
```

**You have to include datatype as html in your ajax call because partial view is
 returning html.**

Comment: hi is this the most efficient way if i was going the form builder route how would one possibly switch between the partial views?

Comment: i m not getting you  @user3824967 are you asking most efficient way to load partial views inside main view.

Comment: Yes I am going be creating a form builder where I load the preview controls using partial views ie in the partial view I would have the various controls ie drop down,text box in partial views then load them according to which control they click. So I am asking what way is best to do a switch statement so that I dont have to right 20 different post methods to change the partial view as you see that example only uses one div divpartialviewcontainer. I will need to load quite a few into one container is that possible without over write the div?

Comment: Look @user3824967 if in your partialviews you are binding dropdowns and want to display data from database then @{Html.RenderAction();} is the best and if you want to show static data or something then @{Html.RenderPartial();} is best and if you want to load partialview's on some click of anything then use ajax call as you are doing...

Comment: Yeah just a question on the forms that mvc 4 produces how html5 compatable are they as that is one of the things my boss said had to be

Comment: yes..absolutely mvc 3+ versions are fully html5 supported you need not to worry...you can easily integrate your forms with bootstrap,foundation etc...

Comment: happy days really liking mvc i used to do this with panel and load controls is their a way then I could save the rendered form to database   its to be like a wuofoo type service for our customers where the html5 form would be presented to them via a url

Comment: @user3824967...i just requesting you to post your question or your scenario on stackoverflow because in comments i will not be able to explain you much..Thankzz...

Comment: is that why i got marked up so much lol i dont have a rep of 15 yet when i do i will

Comment: I asked it here instead as thought more sutied a code review

http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58637/formbuilder-code-make-more-genereic